# Prove a system of simultaneous Diophantine equations has no solution.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've been asked to show that the system of simultaneous Diophantine equations has no solutions:

$3x+6y+z=3$

$12x+3y+2z=5$

I don't even know how to approach this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the first equation, $z$ is divisible by $3$. From the second equation, it cannot be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate $z$: $-6x - 12y - 2z = -6$, and add this to the second equation:

$6x - 9y = -1$ or $3(2x - 3y) = -1$. This shows $3 | -1$ impossible.

Comment: Is there a typo here? Do you not mean eliminate $z$?